# ADODB recordset has always EOF and BOF as True while records exist

Tags: vb6, adodb

I have next code on Visual Basic 6:

```
Static cmd As ADODB.Command
Static rs As ADODB.Recordset
If cmd Is Nothing Then
 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
 rs.ActiveConnection = conn
 Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
 cmd .ActiveConnection = conn
 cmd .CommandText = mySqlCommand
 cmd .Prepared = True
 AddParam cmd, "MyParam", myParam
End IF
SetParam cmd, "MyParam", myParam
rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
While Not rs.EOF
 'Some code...
 '...
 rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
```

I'm totally sure that my command has a result rows. I've tried to log sql command, and then copy-paste it into sqltalk, and it works exactly I've expected - it has a rows.

But in my case in VB I have EOF and BOF always = True.

Why? And how to fix this?

Comment: Try opening the recordset with `adOpenStatic` and `adLockOptimistic` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Put a break point on `While Not rs.EOF` and see what number `rs.RecordCount` returns. If zero, then u have a problem with your query

Comment: rs.RecordCount = -1. But the sql query is right. I logged database activity and then launch the same query manually. It works perfect.

Comment: And the same with adOpenStatic and adLockOptimistic, except now RecordCount=0

Answer (score 0):

Please check the property cursorLocation for recordset and for connection object. I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
While (rsSource.eof = False) And (StopOrShoot = False)

  ' bookmark must have less value that recordcount for use the command .movenext 
  ' if have the same value and you use .movenext EOF gonna be TRUE and you can´t 
  ' read the last row.... 
  ' you try it ...

  If rsSource.RecordCount > rsSource.Bookmark Then
   rsSource.MoveNext   
  Else
    StopOrShoot = True
  End If
Wend
```

Good look...

G. Caseres by Costa Rica